# Animação de um botão (ImageButton) android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como faz para quando o usuario clicar no botão ele ficar maior e menor ao soltar, simulando um efeito de zoom no componente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa o evento onTouchListener, e pegando os MotionEvents dentro desse evento você aumenta/diminui o tamanho.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    int action = motionEvent.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        v.animate().scaleXBy(100f).setDuration(5000).start();
        v.animate().scaleYBy(100f).setDuration(5000).start();
        return true;
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        v.animate().cancel();
        v.animate().scaleX(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
        v.animate().scaleY(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: cara.. pode me dar um exemplo com algum pequeno trecho de código ?

Comment: Editei a resposta com o código ;)